# Who is the voice of DJ Atomika in Burnout Paradise?

Tags: burnout-paradise

I can't tell if the voice of DJ Atomika is familiar, or I've been playing this game so long his voice has become instantly recognizable. Who supplies the voice for DJ Atomika?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this page](http://burnout.wikia.com/wiki/DJ_Atomika) on the Burnout Wiki he's played by [Mark Hildreth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Hildreth_(actor)).

Apparently Mark does the voice for DJ Stryker (the announcer in Burnout: Takedown) too, and both appear in other EA games.

Comment: Thanks.  Looks like I've just been playing the game too long.